# Javascript strip using regex to get before and after an a tag in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string from the server

```
15 Steps is mandatory and must be completed by 14/02/2021: click <a href='http://example.co.uk/training/CRU0007'>here</a> to book/start your learning.
```

I need to get 2 values

```
 15 Steps is mandatory and must be completed by 14/02/2021: click
```

&

```
 to book/start your learning.
```

When I tried this before I had a string wrapped in : and ; and the below code worked

```
var arrStr = newsText.split(/[:;]/);
```

but if I try

```
var arrStr = newsText.split(/[<a></a>]/);
```

I get a jumbled mess.

So I decided to try and use regex and got this far

```
const linkRx = /<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href=(["'])(.*?)\1/;
var arrStr = newsText.split(linkRx);
```

But this leaves the
`>here</a>` in the final part

So how do I edit the regex to get the rest of the a tag. I've searched through lots of answers but they don't seem to get the whole tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [following](https://regex101.com/r/sTzyHL/1) regex.

The purpose is to get wathever is before and after the `<anything></anything>`.

```js
const str = `15 Steps is mandatory and must be completed by 14/02/2021: click <a href='http://example.co.uk/training/CRU0007'>here</a> to book/start your learning.`;

const regex = /(.*?)(?:<.*?>.*?<\/.*?>)(.*)/gm;

const [,
  partA,
  partB,
] = regex.exec(str);

console.log('PartA :', partA);
console.log('PartB :', partB);
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your attempt, could you please try following, Online demo is: [Online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZavOZe/1)

```js
var newsText = `15 Steps is mandatory and must be completed by 14/02/2021: click <a href='http://example.co.uk/training/CRU0007'>here</a> to book/start your learning.`

var arrStr = newsText.split(/\s*<a\s+href=[^>]*>[^>]*<\/a>\s*/);

console.log(arrStr);
```

***Explanation:*** if matches 0+ whitespaces followed by a `<href=` tag and closing `</a>` tag followed by 0+ whitespaces.